# How to update SDK in Android Studio in the background

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.0

Today I'm trying to update the SDK in Android Studio on my Ubuntu, and looking for the menu that make the download process running in the background. So I want to download the SDK and continue to work in Android Studio.

As far as I can remember Eclipse has menu that can download in the background task so I can continue work while downloading.

I've tried to find the option in settings but I could not find it, and on the downloading GUI has no option to download it in the background, here is my screenshot:
[image]

Is anyone having the same issue here? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go to tools -> android -> sdk manager and click on ***Launch stand alone sdk manager*** hyperlink. This will open sdk manager outside android studio, select the packages and download. You can continue to work on android studio this way.

[image]

Comment: looks like they didn't add this feature in android studio so I have to launch standalone SDK Manager

Comment: And how to bring backgroud task to foreground ?

Comment: look like this  option is currently not available in latest studio   version

Answer (score 3):

The "Launch standalone SDK Manager" option seems to be gone in Android Studio 2.3.3 for Windows. However, there is sdkmanager.bat in \tools\bin

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do it all by code using the **sdkmanager tool**.

> The sdkmanager is a command line tool that allows you to view,
>   install, update, and uninstall packages for the Android SDK.

This is an example using the sdkmanager with the command line:

1. First at all, the sdkmanager is located in **android_sdk/tools/bin/**.
2. Go where the sdkmanager is located
3. List installed and available packages using this command:

> sdkmanager --list

The result willl be something similar to this

[image]

4. In my case I want to Download a System Image with Release Name "P" with ABI x86 ( I saw this information from Android Studio)

[image]

5. The next step is to search that system image in your list

[image]

6. Finally install this package in this way:

> ./sdkmanager "system-images;android-P;google_apis;x86"

This will begin the process of downloading the package
[image]

7. After finish you can check that the image is available to use

[image]

For more info: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html#usage

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to latest version of Android Studio (Currently in 2.3.1).
It now support download (both SDK and plugins) in background.